# Кроссдоменная отправка файлов на сервер

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

**js:**

> ```
>   var fd = new FormData();
>   var file = this.files[0];
>   fd.append('file', file);
>   fd.append('qwe', '123');
>   $.ajax({
>     type: 'POST',
>     url: 'url',
>     data: fd,
>     processData: false,
>     contentType: 'multipart/form-data', 
>     success: function(data){
>       alert(data);
>     }
>   });
> ```

**php:**

> ```
> header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
> header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
> print_r($_FILE);
> ```

**Ответ:** array()

В чём моя ошибка?

```
------WebKitFormBoundary0fanYHbVTMJAgcpd  
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="1.jpg"  
Content-Type: image/jpeg

------WebKitFormBoundary0fanYHbVTMJAgcpd  
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="qwe"

123  
------WebKitFormBoundary0fanYHbVTMJAgcpd--
```

Ответ всё тот же.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте

```
processData: false,
contentType: false,
```

Comment: А на тот же домен отправлять пробовали? Или только на другой домен отправляете?

Comment: Только на другой, ибо на исходном нет возможности править PHP.

Comment: Добавьте ещё информацию о браузере. Попробую воспроизвести.